# Get autofill macro to stop if no rows to autofill to

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that pulls certain items out of a database by an autofilter macro and puts them into different sections. I have formulas that go in and are autofilled down to every line in each section. The problem I am running into is if a section only has one line my macro will debug. Below is my code that inserts the formulas and autofills them down. The very last row is the autofill macro and the one I need help with. Can someone please provide me an override that says if there is no lines to autofill to just move on to the next step. I'm not sure how this code would go. Thanks

```
'To insert formulas
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC5<'Data Entry'!R2C2,""*"","""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC18=TRUE,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC2,Database!C[-2]:C[9],11,FALSE),""""),0)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC2,Database!C[-3]:C[8],10,FALSE),"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((VLOOKUP(RC9,Pull!C1:C5,4,FALSE))*RC4,"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((VLOOKUP(RC9,Pull!C1:C5,5,FALSE))*RC4,"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(SUM(RC4,RC6:RC7),"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC2,Database!C[-7]:C[4],6,FALSE),"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC18=TRUE,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC9,'Pull'!C1:C5,2,FALSE),""""),"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC8*RC10,"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC8+RC11,"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC16*R9C13,"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC18=TRUE,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC9,'Pull'!C1:C5,3,FALSE),""""),"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC16*RC14,"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC12/(1-R9C13-RC14),"""")"
Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 3), Cells(Selection.Row, 17)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 3), "Q" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set a LastRow variable, calculated the way you already do, and test whether it's greater than the Selection row:

```
Dim LastRow as Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
...
If LastRow > Selection.Row Then
    Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 3), Cells(Selection.Row, 17)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 3), "Q" & LastRow)
EndIf
```

By the way, if you search on "VBA avoid Select statements" you'll get some info on why that's a good idea and how to do it. In this case I'd set a CellWithFormula variable at the beginning of the code:

```
Dim CellWithFormula as Excel.Range
Set CellWithFormula = Activcell
CellWithFormula.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC5<'Data Entry'!R2C2,""*"","""")"
Set CellWithFormula = CellWithFormula.Offset(0, 1)
```

... and so on.

Comment: Thank you Doug. This worked perfectly. What did you suggest the second part for? What would that help?

Comment: @JamieWalker: the second part is critical to writing good Excel VBA code. Selecting things or activating things causes all kinds of unnecessary issues.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Using `Select` slows things down, among other issues. Like I said, a quick web search will be educational. It's also best just to set an object at the beginning, when you know exactly what and where it is (in this case CellWithFormula) and refer to it thereafter.